# Relation between entropy and information. Is entropy absolute or relative?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

I always thought of entropy as absolute, i.e, many people can measure it for a system and they will all come up with the same number. However, the entropy in statistical mechanics is defined as -Klog(W), where W is the number of states constrained by the initial knowledge of the system that we have.

Now suppose there are 2 people, 1 with little knowledge about the system and 1 who knows everything(perfect knowledge). Now, the person with perfect knowledge can predict what will happen in the next time step in a deterministic universe(let's assume deterministic). So, for him, is it true that the entropy of the universe remains constant with time and for the person with little knowledge, the entropy increases.

Comment: "where W is the number of states constrained by the initial knowledge of the system that we have" - Where are you getting this particular definition? As far as I knew, W was simply the number of microstates associated with a system's current macrostate.

Comment: @probably_someone I was having a discussion with someone that the increase in entropy could be explained by increase in information that results from the collapse of a wavefunction in quantum mechanics and that you can't explain the increase in information by deterministic laws. The other person believed that the increase in entropy is actually dependent on who measures the entropy and a person with perfect knowledge will not see the entropy increase as, for him, he can tell the evolution of the system, hence, no additional information. I am not sure if the W is subject to knowledge or not.

Comment: Knowing exactly which microstate a system is in doesn't change how many microstates there are associated with a given macrostate (and therefore doesn't change the entropy associated with that macrostate). The only thing that can change the entropy associated with a macrostate is if the two observers have entirely different _definitions_ of the macrostate itself (i.e. having different, non-equivalent state variables associated with it). But at that point, you're really talking about two different systems from a statistical-mechanics perspective, the entropy of which aren't directly comparable.

Comment: @probably_someone That's interesting. So, is there a way in which you can justify an increase in information if the universe was deterministic? Boltzmann H-theorem tries to derive second law by kinetic theory but we have the Loschmidt paradox contradicting it

Comment: You need to be careful about the link you're trying to make between thermodynamic entropy and information. More precisely, the thermodynamic entropy is the amount of _extra_ information you need to pick out a particular microstate, given the information contained in the macrostate (in other words, it's the amount of information that's "missing", in a sense, from the macrostate).

Comment: As the universe evolves towards macrostates with more and more microstates, more and more information is needed to pick out any particular microstate. This is what we mean when we say that the entropy of a closed system is non-decreasing (on average) over time. Loschmidt's "paradox" is resolved by the fluctuation theorem.

Comment: @Rishabh Jain,    maybe this is relevant to the issue: "Scientific Uncertainty and Information" (Academic Press, 1964) by Léon Brillouin